# Virtualizing Propertys Recycling and CacheLength

Tags: wpf, xaml

My ListView is set to Virtualziation=true and VirtualizationMode=Recycling.
With .net 4.5 i can set the CacheLength. Then i would have items in Cache which are not actual in the viewport.
The Recycling Property would start to reuse items when scrolling.
So what would happen to cached items? In my understanding they would never used.
Is there a performance improvement to use both propertys at the same time?